# Rpc function created returns an array of users

Tags: postgresql, supabase

I have created an RPC function to retrieve profile data for a user. This function is called from a frontend view, where the logged-in user's ID is passed as an argument. However, the function is currently returning data for all users in the application as they log in, instead of returning only the information for the requested user.

```
  const getProfile = async() => {
    const user = supabase.auth.user();
    let {data, error, status} = await supabase.rpc('get_profile_with_role', {user_id: user.id});
    if(error) throw error;
    if(data && data.length > 0) {
      let cleanUserName = data[0].username ? data[0].username.replace(/['"]+/g, '') : '';
      setUserInfo(data[0]);
    
    }
  }
```

The RPC looks like this.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.get_profile_with_role(user_id uuid)
 RETURNS TABLE(
  id uuid,
  username text,
  name text,
  website text, 
  avatar_url text, 
  welcome_email_sent boolean, 
  has_accepted_privacy_policy boolean,
  country text,
  phone_number text,
  about_me text,
  gender text,
  city text,
  rut text,
  role_id integer
 )
 LANGUAGE sql AS
$func$
SELECT 
  p.id,
  p.username,
  p.name,
  p.website,
  p.avatar_url,
  p.welcome_email_sent,
  p.has_accepted_privacy_policy,
  p.country,
  p.phone_number,
  p.about_me,
  p.city,
  p.rut,
  ur.role_id
FROM 
profiles p
JOIN user_roles ur ON ur.user_id = p.id
where p.id = user_id
$func$;
```

Comment: What version of PostgreSQL? Does it change if you write `WHERE p.id = get_profile_with_role.user_id`?

Comment: Using parameter names matching a column names is generally a bad idea. You have an unqualified reference to `user_id` in your where clause. When an unqualified reference occurs in a SQL statement Postgres first looks into the columns from the mentioned tables. Here it finds the column within a table and there takes that as the referenced value. There your `where` clause is the same as your `on` clause, every row that satisfies the `on` clause also satisfies the `where` clause. As @LaurenzAlbe suggests qualify with the function name or change parameter the names (i.e. p_user_id) and references.

Comment: @Belayer I was asking because in recent PostgreSQL versions, that causes `ERROR:  column reference "%s" is ambiguous`.

Comment: Thanks it works, the query returns a row that had user_id on the column so that was the problem so I changed the parameter name as @Belayer said